# .gitignore file ignoring files I want included

Tags: git, gitignore

A number of files that I **do** want included in the repo were being ignored because I had a mistake in my .gitignore file.

I figured out what I did wrong, but only after I had already committed.

How do I go about updating the repo so that it reads from the updated .gitignore file and these files in question are included?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just update your .gitignore, then when you do `git status` you will see those file again, then do a `git add` on those files/folder you want to add.